# Install PyGObject on Windows

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3, pygobject

I am trying to install PyGObject on Windows 10 with Python 3.5. I know that you download the binaries [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/pygi-aio-3.14.0_rev22-setup.exe/download):

But after downloading the file and running the executable and finding Python's install path, I click on EVERY option and try to import GTK as instructed on their site [here](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html). This is the result:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'gi'
```

How do I get this all working and running?

Answer (score 2):

Well it says "PyGI 3.14.0 AIO rev22 for python 2.7, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 and 3.4" So I imagine it hasn't been updated for 3.5 and it is also 2 major versions behind.

I would suggest just using the [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/) project to get everything.

Comment: I have ran `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pygobject-devel` from MSYS2 and I still get the same python error

Comment: You are using the mingw version of Python installed?

Comment: Yes I am using the mingw version of Python

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-gobject